# Best stitching algorithm for images using OpenGL - C# openTK

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, image-stitching

Below shader code will show three images. I want to stitch these multiple images by using any stitching algorithms.  Found [samples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stitching-input-images-panorama-using-opencv-c/) using openCV. Can I achieve it using c# OpenTK? Please give suggestions.

```
private void Shaders()
{
    /***********Vert Shader********************/
    vertShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
    GL.ShaderSource(vertShader, @"attribute vec3 a_position;
        varying vec2 vTexCoord; 
        void main() {
            vTexCoord=( a_position.xy+1)/2 ;                                 
            gl_Position = vec4(a_position,1);                
        }");
    GL.CompileShader(vertShader);
    /***********Frag Shader ****************/
    fragShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
    GL.ShaderSource(fragShader, @"
        uniform sampler2D sTexture1;
        uniform sampler2D sTexture2;
        uniform sampler2D sTexture3;
        varying vec2 vTexCoord;
        void main ()
        {  
            if ( vTexCoord.x<0.25 ){
                gl_FragColor = texture2D (sTexture3, vec2(vTexCoord.x*2.0, vTexCoord.y));
            }
            else if(vTexCoord.x>=0.25 && vTexCoord.x<0.75 )
            {
                gl_FragColor = texture2D (sTexture1,  vec2(vTexCoord.x*2.0, vTexCoord.y));
            }
            else
            {
                gl_FragColor = texture2D (sTexture2, vec2(1.0- (vTexCoord.x*2.0-1.0), vTexCoord.y));
            }
        }");
    GL.CompileShader(fragShader);
}
```